# What’s wrong with my wilting aloe Vera?

Tags: diagnosis, aloe, wilt

[image]

I’ve been trying not too water it too often or too little but it’s just looking sad. What do you think could be the cause of this and can it be saved?

Comment: lol the least you could do is rotate the picture so we aren't looking sideways at it haha. The plant seems fine to me. Its getting a bit too big for that pot; consider giving it a larger pot.

Comment: Welcome Alexandra! Thanks for your detailed question with the clear picture. I rotated it for you. Picture posting can be difficult here, so it's normal to have a problem on your first try. If it happens again, we'll walk you through the process. I invite you to visit our [help] to learn more about our unique system. [Ask] is a good place to start, and explains why we may ask you for more details. If you need help with any of our features, just let us know. Have fun!

Comment: Getting a bit big for the pot. Looks like you have regular potting soil too. Should you repot, look for a soil that is not quite so moisture retaining. Seems like 90% of the aloe problems seen here come from too much water. Potting soil with acrylamide or other "moisture retainers" can aggravate that.